# Python Json.load JsonDecodeError Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to read the content of a json file with the function defined below but I keep getting the following traceback:

```
def clean_email_list_no_slash(json_obj):
    dirty_dict = {}
    with open(json_obj, 'r') as rdable:
        r = json.load(rdable)
        dirty_dict.update(r)
    for v in dirty_dict.values():
        empty_list = []
        for email in v['email']:
            if not ('/' in email) or not ('\\' in email):
                empty_list.append(email)
        v['email'] = empty_list
    with open(json_obj, 'w') as wtable:
        json.dump(dirty_dict, wtable)
    print('Done.')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/EM/Desktop/Scripts/nocws/draft.py", line 306, in <module>
    clean_email_list_no_slash(json_obj)
  File "c:/Users/EM/Desktop/Scripts/nocws/draft.py", line 292, in clean_email_list_no_slash
    r = json.loads(rdable)
  File "C:\Users\EM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\EM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\EM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I don't get where I am making a mistake.

Here is a sample of the json file:

```
{
    "afghanistan": {
        "website": "http://olympic.af/",
        "facebook links": [
            "https://facebook.com/OlympicOfficial.af"
        ],
        "email": [
            "info@olympic.af"
        ],
        "email_links": [
            "http://olympic.af/contact-us/"
        ],
        "list_of_urls": [
            "http://olympic.af/",
            "http://olympic.af/contact-us/"
        ]
    },
    "albania": { 
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error traceback (btw thanks for posting one. There are so many questions that don't include helpful stuff like this) shows different code to the snippet above it. The error indicates that your *actual* file does not start with either `{` or `[`.

Comment: @quamrana I don't get it, I checked, it starts and closes with curly brackets.

Comment: But are you sure you have the right file? Your error traceback shows different code.

Comment: @quamrana It is the same it's just that I changed a variable's name from `rdablee` to   `rdable` if that's what you mean, all the rest is the same. I deleted the first opening and closing brackets wrapping the data in my file and re-wrote them, form some reason it worked. I still do not know the reason behind that, but for now it did work. Thank you very much for your time.